# Magento 2 Issue while posting the rating with GraphpQL

Tags: api, graphql, magento2

Trying to post a review with rating with Magento GraphQl, but not able to post rating with query. Reviews are properly showing on admin but facing problem with rating. Here what I followed

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/create-product-review.html

```
mutation {
  createProductReview(
    input: {
      sku: "WH08",
      nickname: "Roni",
      summary: "Great looking sweatshirt",
      text: "This sweatshirt looks and feels great. The zipper sometimes sticks a bit.",
      ratings: [
        {
          id: "1",
          value_id: "3"
        }, {
          id: "2",
          value_id: "2"
        }, {
          id: "3",
          value_id: "4"
        }
      ]
    }
) {
    review {
      nickname
      summary
      text
      average_rating
      ratings_breakdown {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation carefully. The **id** and **value_id** values ​​must be base64 encoded.
For example

```
mutation {
  createProductReview(
    input: {
      sku: "WH08"
      nickname: "Roni"
      summary: "Great looking sweatshirt"
      text: "This sweatshirt looks and feels great. The zipper sometimes sticks a bit."
      ratings: [{ id: "MQ==", value_id: "MQ=="}]
    }
  ) {
    review {
      nickname
      summary
      text
      average_rating
      ratings_breakdown {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*"MQ==" value is encoded "1"*